# Number of ways to arrange an object of size n-1 with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to know the number of ways that we can arrange $n-1$ elements such that the last two elements are either $n$ or $n-1$ and after the first occurrence of $n$ or $n-1$ no other element appears other than $n$ or $n-1$. For instance if $n=4$, then the set of possible arrangements will be
$$\{144, 133, 134, 143, 244, 233, 234, 243, 334, 443, 444, 333, 343, 344, 433, 434\}$$ I am having a hard time to generalize a formula. I know before the occurrence of $n$ or $n-1$, we have $n-2$ choices for each position, but as soon as $n$ or $n-1$ appears, I am not sure how to go about it. Does this imply the answer will be a recurrence relation?

Comment: Have you tried finding the complement? 1) Find the number of sequences where "after the first occurrence of n/n-1, no other element appears other than n/n-1, 2) Find the number of such sequences where the last element is < n-1, 3) Find the number of such sequences where the second last element is < n-1.

Comment: for $n=4$ what is the rule that disqualifies  $343, 344, 433, 434$  ?

Comment: @WW1 You are right! I forgot to include them. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to answer this question is to split it up into cases based on how many of the terms are $n$ or $n-1$. If $k$ elements are equal to $n$ or $n-1$, then there are going to be $n-k-1$ elements which are less than $n-1$ at the beginning, and there are going to be $k$ elements which are one of $n-1,n$ at the end. There are $n-2$ ways to choose each of these first $n-k-1$ values, and 2 ways to choose each of the last $k$ values. Thus there are a total of
$$(n-2)^{n-k-1}\cdot 2^k.$$
Then since there are at least two values which are at least $n-1$, we know that $k\geq2$. Then we sum the number of possible strings over all possible values of $k$:
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(n-2)^{n-k-1}\cdot 2^k.$$
However, note that if we multiply this by $(n-2)-2$, we get
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}((n-2)^{n-k-1}\cdot 2^k)((n-2)-2)\\
=&\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}((n-2)^{n-k}\cdot 2^k-(n-2)^{n-k-1}\cdot 2^{k+1})\\
=&\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(n-2)^{n-k}\cdot 2^k-\sum_{k=3}^{n}(n-2)^{n-k}\cdot 2^{k}\\
=&(n-2)^{n-2}\cdot 2^2-(n-2)^{n-n}\cdot 2^{n}\\
=&4((n-2)^{n-2}-2^{n-2}).
\end{align*}
Thus our answer is equal to
$$\frac{4((n-2)^{n-2}-2^{n-2})}{n-4},$$
and that's about as simple as we can get it. Of course, this requires that $n>4$, but in all of these cases it works.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, very clear! just one question, the formula $\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(n-2)^{n-k-1}\cdot 2^k.$ does not seem to work for $n=2$, which can happen. The summation will be form $k=2$ to $1$. It is not too hard to find it for $n=2$ ({12,21}), but I was wondering if the formula can be modified to allow for that.

Comment: Unfortunately this is going to break for $n<3$, since we're assuming that "the last two values are $n$ or $n-1$, implying that there are at least two spaces available. Additionally, this breaks later on too for $n<5$ since we're dividing by $n-4$. I believe the possible answers for $n=2$ should be $\{1,2\}$, though? Sadly I don't think there is a nice way to incorporate these low values without an unnecessarily large equation.

Comment: You are right for $n=2$ they are {1,2} but the cardinality is still 2. Anyways, $\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}(n-2)^{n-k-1}\cdot 2^k$ works for all $n > 2$. I checked it for $n=3$ and $n=4$ and it gives correct answers of 4 and 16. The final formula, which you deduce from it and only relies on $n$, does not work for $n<5$. I feel like the initial formula should work for $n=2$ as well, but maybe it won't. Anyways, thank you again!